# Extract last number out of existing one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to extract the next number out of given numbers. My table contains numbers like below. The main product is always with .1 at the end and could or not contains his subproducts e.g:

```
07.0001.1 (main product)
07.0001.2 (his sub)
07.0001.3 (his sub)
etc..

01.1453.1
01.1453.2
03.3456.1
03.3456.2
03.3456.3
03.5436.1
03.5436.2
03.5436.3
03.5436.4
12.7839.1
12.7839.2
12.3232.1
12.4444.1
12.4444.2
13.7676.1
```

i want to pass first to digits of a number to the query and based on that get all which starts with that and then get the highest number out of next four and return this number + 1.

So if we would take above example inputs if i say `12` then it should find this product: `12.7839.x` and return `12.7839 + 1` so `12.7840`

Another example if i say `03` then should find `03.5436` so `03.5436 + 1` so should return `03.5437`

Hope you know what i mean.

I am not so familiar with SQL but this is how far i am:

```
select * from tbArtikel where Nummer LIKE '12.%'
```

Comment: Seems like you have crammed three values into one dot-delimited column.  Your query, and your life, would be much simpler if you just had three columns. If you desperately need that composite value as a column, create a view that outputs the dot-delimited expression as an extra column.

Comment: Am I correct that you actually have two questions: 1) how to search by partial number 2) how to autoincrement?

Answer (score 2):

This is another alternate for achieving the desired results. Providing the option to pass number to be queried. Consider following SQL statements

```
CREATE TABLE tblDummyExample
(
    Number      VARCHAR(64)
)


INSERT INTO tblDummyExample 
VALUES ('07.0001.1')
, ('07.0001.2')
, ('07.0001.3')
, ('01.1453.1')
, ('01.1453.2')
, ('03.3456.1')
, ('03.3456.2')
, ('03.3456.3')
, ('03.5436.1')
, ('03.5436.2')
, ('03.5436.3')
, ('03.5436.4')
, ('12.7839.1')
, ('12.7839.2')
, ('12.3232.1')
, ('12.4444.1')
, ('12.4444.2')
, ('13.7676.1')


DECLARE @startWith VARCHAR(2) = '12'        -- provide any number as input

SELECT @startWith + '.'+ CAST((MAX(CAST(SUBSTRING(ex.Number, (CHARINDEX('.', ex.Number, 1) + 1), (CHARINDEX('.', ex.Number, (CHARINDEX('.', ex.Number, 1) + 1)) - (CHARINDEX('.', ex.Number, 1) + 1))) AS INT)) + 1) AS VARCHAR(16))
FROM tblDummyExample ex
WHERE ex.Number LIKE @startWith+'%'
```

I'm sure, this solution is not restricted to any specific SQL Server version.

Comment: Well, `PARSENAME` exists since SS2005 :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, extract the first two parts, convert the 2nd to a numeric value, add one and convert back to a string again:

```
select
    parsename(max(nummer), 3) + '.'                    -- 03
    + ltrim(max(cast(parsename(nummer, 2) as int) +1)) -- 5436 -> 5437
    + '.1'                                          
from tbArtikel 
where Nummer LIKE '03.%'
```

Comment: i understand that if there will net passed number at all this will return NULL correct? I made some tests and seems to be working. I am planniing to deploy on production are you sure it will always works as i presented?:)

Comment: @JohnDoe: "*net passed number*" = "no passed number"? If there's no matching number no row will be returned. "*deploy on production*"  within half an hour? Agile...

Comment: i ment: if the first two digits will not be existing in db even once, so no product starting with passed value, it will return null correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (col VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @table
VALUES ('01.1453.1')
    ,('01.1453.2')
    ,('03.3456.1')
    ,('03.3456.2')
    ,('03.3456.3')
    ,('03.5436.1')
    ,('03.5436.2')
    ,('03.5436.3')
    ,('03.5436.4')
    ,('12.7839.1')
    ,('12.7839.2')
    ,('12.3232.1')
    ,('12.4444.1')
    ,('12.4444.2')
    ,('13.7676.1')

SELECT TOP 1 left(col, charindex('.', col, 1) - 1) + '.' + convert(VARCHAR(10), convert(INT, substring(col, charindex('.', col, 1) + 1, charindex('.', col, charindex('.', col, 1) + 1) - (charindex('.', col, 1) + 1))) + 1)
FROM @table
WHERE col LIKE '03.%'
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```